# How do I center an ImageView and a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here my layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"/>

     <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image2"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to center the TextView with the ImageView above it. How do I do this?

I want to it to look like this:

```
<Player_Image> <Player_Name_Points>
<Player_Image> <Player_Name_Points>
```

Comment: the are two imageviews and two textview which one you wanna to center

Comment: Also you can make screenshot from eclipse (DDMS, under devices there is an icon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try doing this ...I think you will get it what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `ScrollView` use a `ListView` with a custom item containing the image and text inside a `LinearLayout` (other layouts will work).  Use `wrap_content` for the widths and `center` for the gravity.

Bind an adapter e.g. `ArrayAdapter` to the `ListView` to control the data that is shown.